# Create Entity Manager in Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an existing entity in a Symfony3 project that I am trying to add an entity manager to.  My doctrine.yml file looks like this

```
doctrine:
 dbal:
  default_connection: default
    connections:
     default: 
      driver:   pdo_mysql
      host:     localhost
      port:     3306
      dbname:   fullstackdb
      user:     root
      password: root
      charset:  UTF8

   lego:
     driver:   pdo_mysql
     host:     localhost
     port:     3306
     dbname:   fullstackdb
     user:     root
     password: root
     charset:  UTF8


  orm:
   default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
     auto_mapping: true
     default:
      connection: default
       mappings:

    lego:
      connection: lego
       mappings:
        AppBundle: ~
```

However anytime I try to access this entity manager through php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=lego
, it says the manager does not exist!  I'm not sure if I'm missing a step - the only thing I've done to create the manager is to make the yml file.

It doesn't show up when I run bin/console debug:container.
 Grateful for any help!

Comment: How are you trying to access it?  Does bin/console debug:container show it?

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to access it through php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=lego and it doesn't show up when I run that command!

Comment: @Nespony In your example yaml the indentation is incorrect. If this is not a copy and paste or SO formatting issue then it could be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are using the same schema name (database name) on the same host in two different entity managers without schema_filters. This means that when you do an update to one of the entity managers it will attempt to delete the data of the other entity manager.

2) You are asking about a entity manager but in the command you are passing a connection.

3) Run php bin/console debug:container | grep doctrine

This will give you all the doctrine services. Update your question accordingly.

4) Provide the exact command and exact error you get so we can track it down to the origin

5) For a more information run the command in verbose mode adding -v at the end

6) Are you importing your doctrine.yml in your config.yml ?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't imported doctrine.yml in to the config.yml!